# Making self-referencing models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rest, activerecord

All,

I'm still working my way around learning Rails and I'm not having much luck finding the relevant answers I need; that said, I suspect it's something that's been done before since I've done this by hand many times in the past myself.

I have a table called tab_accounts with account_id(int) as PK. I also have a lookup table called mtom_account_relations. This table has two int columns (account_subject, account_associate), both of which are FK to tab_accounts.account_id. The purpose of this layout is to allow for a many-to-many relationship between tab_account entries. The goal is to create an endpoint that returns an account's details along with a list of its associates, also accounts.

At this point I have the following:

models/account_relation.rb:

```
class AccountRelation < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "mtom_account_relations"
  belongs_to :subject, foreign_key: "account_id", class_name: "Account"
  belongs_to :associate, foreign_key: "account_id", class_name: "Account"
end
```

models/account.rb

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "tab_accounts"
  self.primary_key = "account_id"
  ...
  has_many :account_relations
  has_many :associates, :through => :account_relations
  has_many :subjects, :through => :account_relations
end
```

controllers/account_controller.rb

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def associates
    _account_id = params[:account_id]
    @rs_account = Account
                      .select("tab_accounts.account_id, tab_accounts.screen_name, tab_accounts.friends, tab_accounts.followers")
                      .where(:tab_accounts => {account_id: _account_id})
                      .as_json[0]
    @rs_account['associates'] = Account.select("tab_accounts.account_id, tab_accounts.screen_name")
                                      .joins(:subjects)
                                      .where(:tab_accounts => {account_id: _account_id})
                                      .as_json
    render json: @rs_account
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  get 'accounts/associates/:account_id', :to => "accounts#associates"
end
```

When I run the method I get the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column mtom_account_relations.account_id does not exist LINE 1: ..._accounts" INNER JOIN "mtom_account_relations" ON "mtom_acco... ^ : SELECT tab_accounts.account_id, tab_accounts.screen_name FROM "tab_accounts" INNER JOIN "mtom_account_relations" ON "mtom_account_relations"."account_id" = "tab_accounts"."account_id" INNER JOIN "tab_accounts" "subjects_tab_accounts" ON "subjects_tab_accounts"."account_id" = "mtom_account_relations"."account_id" WHERE "tab_accounts"."account_id" = $1
```

1. I suspect the call to the non-existent table "subjects_tab_accounts" is being created from my .joins(:subjects) clause in the controller.
2. It thinks there's a "mtom_account_relations"."account_id" column.

I'd be grateful for any actionable assistance. Thank you for your attention.

- Joe

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example of a family tree. Since Person can be either in the `parent_id` or `child_id` column setting up `has_many :relationships` relation won't work since we don't know which column to use in the join.

Instead we need to setup separate relationships depending on which foreign key on Relationship we joining and then query through this relationship

```
class Person
  has_many :relationships_as_child,
    class_name: 'Relationship'
    foreign_key: 'child_id'
  has_many :relationships_as_parent,
    class_name: 'Relationship'
    foreign_key: 'parent_id'

  has_many :parents, 
    through: :relationships_as_child,
    source: :parent
  has_many :children, 
    through: :relationships_as_child,
    source: :child
end

class Relationship
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Person'
  belongs_to :child, class_name: 'Person'
end
```

---

```
class AccountRelation < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "mtom_account_relations"
  belongs_to :subject, 
     foreign_key: "account_id", 
     class_name: "Account"
  belongs_to :associate, foreign_key: "account_id", 
     class_name: "Account"
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "tab_accounts"
  self.primary_key = "account_id"
  ...
  has_many :account_relations_as_subject,
    class_name: 'AccountRelation', 
    foreign_key: 'subject_id'

  has_many :account_relations_as_associate,
    class_name: 'AccountRelation',
    foreign_key: 'associate_id'

  has_many :associates, 
    through: :account_relations_as_subject,
    source: :associate

  has_many :subjects,
    through: :account_relations_as_associate,
    source: :subject
end
```

When learning Rails I would really encourage you to learn to love the conventions when it comes to naming tables, primary keys and columns in general. Don't make it harder on yourself.

When it comes to the controller I would set it up like so:

```
#routes.rb
resources :accounts do
  resources :associates, only: [:index]
end

class AssociatesController
  # GET /accounts/:account_id/associates
  def index
    @account = Account.joins(:associates).find(params[:account_id])
    @associates = @account.associates
  end
end
```

This models associates as a RESTful resource which is nested under an account and gives you straight forward and conventional way to add more CRUD actions.